# Ruby - IO#ioctl throws range error in 1.9.3 but not 1.9.1 for 32bit

Tags: ruby, io, 32bit-64bit

```
ruby-1.9.1-p243 :008 > a,b = IO.pipe
=> [#<IO:0x2010670>, #<IO:0x2010654>] 
ruby-1.9.1-p243 :009 > a.ioctl(0x80000000, "\x00\x00")
    Errno::ENOTTY: Inappropriate ioctl for device
    from (irb):9:in `ioctl'
    from (irb):9
    from /Users/dlampa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p243/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

This would work if the IO object were an appropriate device and the command was valid.

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :022 > a,b = IO.pipe
=> [#<IO:fd 9>, #<IO:fd 10>] 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :023 > a.ioctl(0x80000000, "\x00\x00")
RangeError: bignum too big to convert into `long'
    from (irb):23:in `ioctl'
    from (irb):23
    from /Users/dlampa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

On MacOSX 10.6.8

I'm assuming that this has something to do with bit signing (maybe), and have packed and unpacked things as signed and unsigned, but nothing seems to prevent 1.9.3 from throwing that range error. Of course, there's no problem in 64-bit implementations. I'm totally confused. Can someone explain why this is happening and perhaps provide a workaround?

Edit: 
The command also works in 1.9.2-p290, so there was definitely a change from 1.9.2 to 1.9.3

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > a,b = IO.pipe
 => [#<IO:fd 3>, #<IO:fd 4>] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > a.ioctl(0x80000000, "\x00\x00")
Errno::ENOTTY: Inappropriate ioctl for device
    from (irb):2:in `ioctl'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/dlampa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Apparently, this is a bug in ruby 1.9.3. See: [link](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6127) for more details.